# accessing kohana auth hash_password method

Tags: php, kohana

I want to use kohana auth hash_password method for authentication purposes outside the context of the normal session based login. (for a simple api)

I have tried several ways. Simply instantiating a the auth class does not work because it is an abstract class. I tried to call the method statically, that obviously did not work. Lastly I tried created a new class called authenticate that extends the auth class and instantiating that one. I get the following error

> Class Authenticate contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be
>   declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (Kohana_Auth::_login, Kohana_Auth::password,
>   Kohana_Auth::check_password)

Not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try Auth::factory()->hash_password($pass) which will create a new Auth object with no user data associated with it or Auth::instance() which will pick up the currently instantiated Auth object if there is one.

Comment: ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: 
Cannot instantiate abstract class Auth

Comment: You may need to call Kohana::Auth::factory().  I would check but I don't have a working PHP install in front of me.

Comment: Maybe the Auth module isn't active?  I'm not sure why it won't initialize the class.

Comment: Im already using the auth module fine for access control throughout the site. Now I want to use the hash_password method for a web service api I am making. Using login() would come along with session creation etc etc.. I don't need that for the api.